# how to prevent the user to drag HTML input type='range' right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three input type='range' fields that have different max values but share the same capacity. This capacity is decreased with every change on either of the three inputs. When the capacity reaches 0 I am supposed to prevent the input fields from moving right ( from increasing their value ) and only move left, but I dont know how to do it using JS and jQuery

here is the html for the inputs

```
<input type="range" class="slider" id="woodSlider" min="0" value="0" max="1558">
<input type="range" class="slider" id="ironSlider" min="0" value="0" max="2555">
<input type="range" class="slider" id="stoneSlider" min="0" value="0" max="2451">
```

and here is the code that decreases the capacity:

```
$("input").change(function() {  
    $("#capacityLeft").html(parseInt(holding.capacity) - 
         $("#woodSlider").val() -
         $("#ironSlider").val() -
         $("#stoneSlider").val());
    if(parseInt($("#capacityLeft").html()) <= 0) {
    // TODO: FIND OUT HOW TO STOP THE SLIDERS FROM MOVING
    }
});
```

Comment: Setting the max value of each one to `capacity` minus the values of the other two sounds like a start.

Comment: I have a working solution on jsfiddle, I can post it once you share what you have already tried / your current code and explanation where you're stuck.

Comment: @vank091 OK, I've posted my solution.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, so you can use `event.preventDefault()` to stop an event. You should bind a function to `onchange` or `oninput` events on these range sliders and calculate the sum, check if it exceed the max, then stop the event if it does.

[**Here's a pure JS solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/EL4tf/) (fiddle link), could be easily rewritten with jQuery.

```
var maxTotal = 150, // define the max sum of values
    inputs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input')), // refrence to the elements
    getTotal = function(){ // helper function to calculate the sum
        var sum = 0;
        inputs.forEach( function(input){
           sum += parseInt(input.value, 10); 
        });
        return sum;
    },
    maxReached = function(e){  // check if the max is reached
        var sum = getTotal(), target;
        if(sum > maxTotal){
            target = e.target;
            // set the max possible value if the user, for example, clicks too far to the right
            target.value = target.value - (sum - maxTotal);
            // next line is just for demonstrational purposes
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = getTotal();

            // prevent increasing the value
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        // next line is just for demonstrational purposes
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = getTotal();

        // everything's fine, nothing to do.
        return true;
    };

// attach the maxReached function to your inputs
inputs.forEach( function(input){
    input.addEventListener('input', maxReached );
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the `target.value = target.value - (sum - maxTotal);` part is the key. It just overrides the value with the maximum for that slider every time it gets larger than that. It took me a while to understand why the `return false;` didn't work alone.

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled around for a while, and this is what I was able to custom set the input range's value with (this code basically implements a "toggle" button):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('myInput');
let currentValue = 0;
input.onclick = function(e) {
  currentValue = 1 - currentValue;
  e.target.value = currentValue;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" style="width: 600px;" />
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6v1h4but/)

I used `onclick` because I wanted it to respond every time the user clicks anywhere on the input range, not just when the user "changes the value" according to the browser. Obviously, use `oninput` or `onchange` if you only want to fire an event when the user changes the slider position.

It does appear to be the case that you need to manually set/override the `e.target.value` as the `return false;` is not really doing anything. In fact, **the above code works just the same without returning false**.

---

For mobile, however, you need to use `ontouchstart` instead of `onclick`. You also need to `return false;` for it to work.